# Use custom tag using JavaScript only

Tags: javascript, html

On my site, as a little footer I guess, I use the tag `<joexn id="yo">`
and the javascript

```
var div = document.getElementById('yo');
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeBegin', 'joexn.com' );
```

This produces a watermark/footer and want I want to know is how can I change it so the tag is just `<joexn>` using Javascript only. I want minimalist code only and no clutter. I tried using `document.getElementByTagName('joexn');` but that didn't work.

What's the easiest method?

**I don't know why this has been marked as duplicate, it is nothing like that other question.**

Comment: div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeBegin', 'joexn' ) ?

Comment: No, that just adds my website link, that won't change.

Comment: Use `querySelector` or `querySelectorAll` to get a reference. Additionally, you need a closing tag too (`</joexn>`).

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a HTMLCollection, just like `getElementsByClassName` explained in the other question.

Comment: @joexn Interesting reading: [Custom Elements](http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/V).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try using [document.querySelector()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector): **[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/4t4tcr3w/)**

```
var div = document.querySelector('joexn');
div.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeBegin', 'joexn.com' );
```

Answer (score 0):

`document.getElementsByTagName('joexn')` should work. Mind you, you have a typo in the usage of this method. It is `getElements` and not `getElement`.

This method returns an HTMLCollection object which is an array-like object. So, to get the element itself, you can do

`var joexnElement = document.getElementsByTagName('joexn')[0];`

And, then do the rest...

Comment: That's strange, `getElement` works still. I'll try out this one more time and I'll see if `document.getElementsByTagName('joexn')` works.

Comment: It seems like `document.querySelector` works perfectly. Thank your for your reply but `document.getElementsByTagName('joexn')` doesn't work for me.